# Nvd3 legend vertically placed but want it to be horizantal

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 for drawing line chart for two series.As u can see in plunk [PlunkLink](https://plnkr.co/edit/mMi5bAg9PApelOQ9JmPT?p=preview) my legends are stacked vertically .I want them to be horizantal for this width. Note: I can't edit the nvd3.js and also cant increase the width of chart for my app.I have tried few suggestions but it didn't work for line chart.Ty for ur response

```
 nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .x(function(d) {

            return new Date(d.time)
        })

    .y(function(d) {

        return d.value
    })
        .color(["#FF0000", "#000000"])



        .useInteractiveGuideline(false)
        .forceY(0)
        .width(300)
        .height(200)

    ;


    chart.xAxis
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d))
        });
    chart.xScale(d3.time.scale.utc());

    chart.options({
        noData: "Not enough data to graph",
        rightAlignYAxis: false,
    });

    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('values'));

    d3.select('nv-indexLine').fill("black");
    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(formattedData)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    chart.lines.interactive(false);

    return chart;
});
```

Comment: You may have to translate the legends to a position of your choice post drawing.

Comment: hi cyril ,with translate i'm able to move them but not sure how to increase the width of the legend-wrap so that they come inline...

Comment: the legend-wrap is a group so its width is the same as the bbox of all its elements. So you dont need to worry about it.Just translate the group with class `nv-series`.